# Asp.Net Core: Access custom AuthorizeAttribute property in AuthorizeHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

As I am working on `Asp.Net core Authorization` part, I needed a new property in `AuthorizeAttribute` which I want to utilize as a extra permission value. So, I have extended the `AuthorizeAttribute` in my own custom Authorize attribute. See below:

```
public class RoleAuthorizeAttribute : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Permission { get; private set; }

        public RoleAuthorizeAttribute(string policy, string permission) : base(policy)
        {
            this.Permission = permission;
        }
    }
```

Then, I've created an `AuthorizationHandler` to check for the requirement as below:

```
public class RolePermissionAccessRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<RolePermissionDb>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolePermissionDb requirement)
        {
            // check here..
            context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

All respective service collection mapping I have already done, just omitted here.

Now, I want my attribute to use like this on controller action level:

```
[RoleAuthorize("DefaultPolicy", "CustomPermission")]
public IActionResult List()
{
}
```

Would anybody suggest me **how would I access the permission property value given on the top of Action method in the handler RolePermissionAccessRequirement** ??

I want to perform some sort of access rule based on custom permission value given in the `Authorize attribute` on top of Action method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To parametrize a custom `Authorize` attribute, create an authorization filter implementing `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`. Then wrap the filter in a `TypeFilterAttribute`-derived attribute. This attribute can accept parameters and pass it to the authorization filter's constructor.

Usage example:

```
[AuthorizePermission(Permission.Foo, Permission.Bar)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AuthorizePermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizePermissionAttribute(params Permission[] permissions)
        : base(typeof(PermissionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new[] { new PermissionRequirement(permissions) };
        Order = Int32.MinValue;
    }
}    

public class PermissionFilter : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authService;
    private readonly PermissionRequirement _requirement;

    public PermissionFilter(
        IAuthorizationService authService, 
        PermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        //you can inject dependencies via DI            
        _authService = authService;

        //the requirement contains permissions you set in attribute above
        //for example: Permission.Foo, Permission.Bar
        _requirement = requirement;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool ok = await _authService.AuthorizeAsync(
            context.HttpContext.User, null, _requirement);

        if (!ok) context.Result = new ChallengeResult();
    }
}
```

In addition, register a `PermissionHandler` in DI to handle `PermissionRequirement` with permission list:

```
public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
```

Look at this [this](https://github.com/ilya-chumakov/PaperSource.AspNetCoreAuthorization) GitHub project for a complete example.